# How to start service using external intent?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I'd like to know if it's possible to start service using intents sent from another app? I've a Broadcast Receiver for `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`and it works even though at the time when the intent is received BrodcastReceiver class for it is not instancionated. I did something similar for external intents from tasker but it doesn't work.

```
<receiver android:name="BootReceiver">  
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
    </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to know if it's possible to start service using intents sent from another app?

Sure.

> I've a Broadcast Receiver for android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETEDand it works even though at the time when the intent is received BrodcastReceiver class for it is not instancionated.

That is because manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver` objects are not instantiated ahead of time. They are only created when a matching broadcast is sent.

> I did something similar for external intents from tasker but it doesn't work.

"it doesn't work" is insufficient information for anyone to help you.

But, if you have a `<service>` with an `<intent-filter>`, other apps can create an `Intent` matching your `<intent-filter>` and use that to start (or bind to) your service. There are two exceptions:

1. If you add `android:exported="false"` to the `<service>`, third party apps cannot invoke it at all, though you would be better served simply getting rid of the `<intent-filter>` in that case
2. If you use `android:permission` on the `<service>` element, the other app needs to hold your stated permission in order to start or bind to your service

Comment: very useful note about android:exported. It solved my issue.